# Find average CPU, vMem, sMem usage on 1, 5, and 15min

Tags: memory, python, cpu, command

I am trying to find at time T the average CPU usage on 1, 5, and 15min, just like what you get from `/proc/loadavg`

Same thing for virtual memory, and swap memory.

I would be fine with a python library too, I've looked into `psutils` and `procfs` without success.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `vmstat` does what you need.

From the man page:

> vmstat  reports information about processes, memory, paging, block IO,
>   traps, disks and cpu activity.
>
> The first report produced gives averages since the  last  reboot.
>   Additional  reports give  information on a sampling period of length
>   delay.

Answer (score 1):

if you have sysstat installed you can use sar command

e.g

```
sar -q
               runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15   blocked
16:49:01            0       173      0.00      0.01      0.05         1
16:50:01            0       173      0.00      0.01      0.05         0
```

> from sar 's man page
>
> -q
>       Report queue length and load averages. The following values are displayed:

Comment: IIRC, `sar` needs daily files to function properly. I need a way to find at any time the average CPU and RAM usage with what is already on the system.
I think I will just look in `/proc` and do the parsing myself

Comment: sysstat collects all system stats using a cron and if that has not been run you cannot get any statistics using it. It does not use /proc for historical data.